# How should I answer questions about what I'm "expecting from my PhD" and "what I'll do after my PhD"?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path, interview, germany

I am in the fourth semester of my master's in a poor Asian country and want to do a PhD in pure mathematics in France or Germany.

**I am asking how should I answer these two probable questions in my PhD interview:**

1. *What are you expecting from your PhD?*

   I think I will say that I will put hard work in my research  during my PhD and will take part in whatever teaching activities are assigned to me by the department. I expect that I will publish 2-3 research papers.

   Is this answer fine?
2. *What are you expecting after your PhD?*

   I think  I will say that I will do a couple of postdocs in Europe or in North America and continue my research. After that, I will join a university as an assistant professor.

   Should I specify country here? I don't want to live or teach in my home country because of terrible political conditions and social conditions, should I say that I would like to work in Europe or North America (I know to  be able to do that is very hard)?

   Or I should avoid mentioning that and just say that I would like to join a university as assistant professor. What if then I am asked in my home country or any other country?

Comment: Did you consider thinking about these questions carefully and then giving an honest answer? That would probably be the best thing to do. Obviously we cannot do that for you because we do not know your motives. Voting to close.

Comment: Looks like they have thought about them carefully, given an honest answer, included it in the question, and are looking for advice on whether there are any accidental red flags that could turn  a potential supervisor away

Comment: @Louic I have thought it carefully and added my thoughts in the question itself

Comment: @E.Rei ya, you are right.

Comment: (i) These answers don't feel very natural but rather like something you think the other side might hear, at least from a european perspectice. (ii) The answer to point 1 does not at all answer what you expect from your PhD - it only says what your future advisor can expect from you. Or is your motivation why you want to do a PhD to do hard work? Not to learn exciting new things, get to know people, and whatever else ...

Comment: By the way, I don't think either of these questions is very probable.

Comment: A much more likely question would be "Why do you want to do your PhD with us"?

Comment: "I will put hard work [...] and [...] take part in whatever [...] activities are assigned to me [...]" - noooooo! Don't say that! At least in European culture, it is perceived as between being hopelessly lost and offensively not caring. This seems to be a common point of conflict, too: a hard worker who is not independent is a *nightmare* for the advisor. So, the qualities the department would normally seek are: 1) Independent thinking/ability to work solo and 2) Hard working. In that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your ultimate goal is to join academia as a profession, the second question should emphasize that. Say that you'd eventually like to become a professor in Europe or North America. You don't need to talk about post-docs, but say that you will work to stay on track to that goal.

As for the first question, it isn't about what you intend to *do* so much as what you want to learn and accomplish as a doctoral student. You want to, I hope, become grounded both in your field and in effective research in that field. If you have a small sub-field in mind or a particular person to study with, mention that.

The situation in your home country is not relevant for this, but you might be asked at some point, and you can answer then.

The actual path to your short and long term goals is fairly standardized and hard, but you don't need to spell it out, since it is known already. Talk about the goals.

Comment: Isn't a person  from poor Asian Country mentioning about aiming for Professorship in Europe considered as too ambitious ( Also, whether the natives of the country like to employ people from other nations to academic positions is another things that come to mind)? So, should I say that I would like to join as assistant prof in my country ( and then later while I am a PhD student with them I will mention that I would like to be in Academia in Europe or North America?)

Comment: Your country of origin shouldn't be relevant. But if you are uncomfortable, just say you hope to eventually become a professor in your field, not mentioning any country and not specifying "assistant". You want to get in to a good program. Focus on that.

Comment: @No-One No-one who is clear in their mind will expect that at the beginning of the PhD you need to know whether a career in academia is for you, and what kind of career. If this is what you have in mind, there's nothing wrong with saying that, but you don't have to say this to make a good case. (Unless, of course, you say "I just want to do a PhD to have a PhD".) So I think the issue with sounding overly/underly ambitious in that regard is low. Personally, I find people who know for sure what they want to do in 20 years somewhat intimidating, even more so when they are only 25 years old ...